# ¿Como ejecutar Script de MySql en el primer lanzamiento de mi aplicación?

Tags: java, administración-de-software

Estoy terminando de desarrollar una aplicación de escritorio en JavaFx con conexión a MySQL Server para una pequeña institución educativa, la aplicación en un ambiente de pruebas y desarrollo (Un pc con mysql instalado y la base de datos montada) funciona correctamente por lo que esta lista para llevarla a un ambiente de mundo real, pero me encuentro con que la institución cuenta con las siguientes carencias:

- Carece de un departamento encargado de Soporte TI
- Carece de personal capacitado para realizar una instalación y configuración compleja
- Poco presupuesto para poder contratar a personal que pueda realizar la instalacion

Por lo que es de vital importancia añadir un modulo para que el 'Usuario' pueda ejecutar el Script desde la misma aplicación ya sea al iniciar la aplicación por primera vez o durante la instalación de la misma, así solo se tendrá que preocupar por la instalación y configuración de MySQL server que estará documentada en un manual de instalación, por otro lado he estado investigando la manera de hacerlo desde mismo Java pero no me queda muy claro como hacerlo.

Entiendo que es una pregunta muy complicada de responder, pero espero que con su experiencia puedan ayudarme o brindarme un consejo sobre como podría solucionarlo.

Comment: No creo que el camino correcto sea poner en el `Main` cierto tipo de código que quieres ejecutar **solamente en la instalación de la App** (si lo pones en el `Main` ese código se ejecutará siempre que la App se abra). En JavaFX se contempla la posibilidad de crear **un verdadero instalador**: [Deploying JavaFX Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm), el cual tiene información interesante que te guiará hacia la creación de un instalador de tu App con código para ejecutar por ejemplo la creación de la base de datos y las tablas que manejará la aplicación.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que quiere hacer OP no es incorrecto. Si fuera un upgrade de la app los cambios en general se hacen cuando la app arranca.

Comment: Vas a tener que hacer varias cosas. Versionar la base de datos. De alguna manera darle soporte de backup desde la app. Generar un instalador que cree toda la configuracion, incluido como conectarse a una base de datos. Son muchos pasos.

Comment: *los cambios en general se hacen cuando la app arranca* ... No necesariamente @gbianchi, en las aplicaciones normales (casi todas las que usamos a diario) no ocurre eso, sino que se instala una nueva versión de la App. Lo mismo podemos hacer hoy día con nuestras aplicaciones. Las podemos incluso dotar de un actualizador que busque en un servidor si la versión actual es menor que una posible versión más nueva. Si hay actualizaciones disponibles, entonces la App puede descargar un nuevo paquete que ejecute otro tipo de scripts  (una primera instalación no es lo mismo que una actualización)...

Comment: ... en la primera instalación por ejemplo se crearía la base de datos, el usuario administrador, etc... en la actualización no se tocaría a la base de datos (salvo en caso de que sea necesario debido a errores en su diseño inicial), se corregirían posibles errores encontrados en las viejas versiones de la App. Hoy día no hay ninguna dificultad para hacer que nuestras Apps funcionen de forma totalmente profesional. Poner todo eso en el `Main` me parece una chapuza lamentable.

Comment: @A.Cedano es lo que busco, que durante la primera instalación se ejecute el script de mysql, ya he generado un instalador con el enlace que mencionas en tu comentario,  pero no encuentro lo relacionado con el script, e incluso he generado un instalador con inno setup pero lo del script sigue sin resolverse, no se pudieras darme un consejo mas especifico de como hacerlo

Comment: @gbianchi En la app ya agregue lo que mencionas, contiene un apartado para que el usuario pueda generar y restaurar backups, y como mencionas necesito generar un instalador que cree toda la configuración ese es el problema que no se resolver, he creado un instalador con inno setup pero no pude encontrar algo relacionado con que pueda ejecutar scripts de mysql durante la instalacion

Comment: Vas a tener que tener procedimientos manuales (que si no recuerdo mal puedes hacer) donde hagas una instalacion silenciosa de mysql, lo configures y todo sin que el usuario sepa. Luego de eso, tu programa puede generar en su primer ejecucion todo lo que se necesite.

Comment: y No @A.Cedano.. aunque no lo creas, se usa mas veces de las que vos crees. Los upgrade por web, en general lo unico que hacen es actualizar los ejecutables. Despues de eso, al ejecutar tu programa, llamas a un procedimiento que verifica si todo esta al corriente. Para mas ejemplos, lo hace wordpress comunmente (ante cada actualizacion de todo, al levantar el administrador corre exactamente esos procesos) y EF (entityframework en .net) lo tiene embebido al lanzar el codigo. No haces un instalador con todos los cambios. Si hay que modificar datos, no lo puedes hacer en el instalador.

Comment: @gbianchi hay alguna manera de como saber cuando es la primera ejecución de la aplicación? También estuve leyendo que se puede utilizan un preloader personalizado pero desconozco el tema...

Comment: un preloader.. todo en el main.. la teoria es la misma. No importa que ejecucion de la app es. De alguna manera tenes que saber si la BD esta actualizada. Basta con comprobar si un campo esta presente segun la ultima actualizacion.. o tener una tabla con version de BD (igual que como tenes la version del exe y sabes si se actualizo). Las estrategias son multiples...

Comment: pasa por el [chat] si necesitas mas info

Answer (score 0):

Voy a tratar de responderte de una manera resumida. Incluyo links que te valdrán para ir guiándote en el desarrollo.

> 1. Necesitas un controlador [JDBC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). Con él podrás [conectar a la base de datos MySQL desde Java](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html).
> 2. Los programas Java, empiezan por la [clase "main" o principal](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=622:codigo-ejemplo-clase-con-metodo-main-en-java-sintaxis-con-string-args-ejecutar-un-programa-cu00656b&catid=68&Itemid=188).  Deberás poner al principio de este método la llamada a todo lo que
>      quieras que se ejecute "al principio".
> 3. Necesitarás un [FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java) para leer el fichero donde dejes la query MySQL.